# How would I test a no events yet logic with from RxJava with Project Reactor Stepverifier?

Tags: junit, project-reactor

I'm currently trying to figure out, how to do a similar test in Project Reactor.
Basically I want to ensure that before connect no events occur.

```
@Test
void connectable() {
    Observable<String> provider = Observable.just("Test1", "Test2");
    ConnectableObservable<String> connectable = provider.publish();
    TestObserver<String> testSubscriber = connectable.test();
    testSubscriber.assertEmpty();
    connectable.connect();
    testSubscriber.assertResult("Test1", "Test2").assertComplete();
}
```

This is my current attempt, but it is not correct, how would I get this to work?

```
@Test
void connectable() {
    Flux<String> provider = Flux.just("Test1", "Test2");
    ConnectableFlux<String> connectable = provider.publish();
    FirstStep<String> tester = StepVerifier.create(connectable).expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMinutes(1));
    connectable.connect();
    tester.expectNext("Test1", "Test2").expectComplete().verify();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. `StepVerifier` tests the sequence as a whole and you cannot add imperative assertions in the middle. But you can make your assertions and state-modifying calls within the `StepVerifier`! For that, use `then(Runnable)`:

```
@Test
public void stepVerifierTestConnect() {
    Flux<String> provider = Flux.just("Test1", "Test2");
    ConnectableFlux<String> connectable = provider.publish();

    StepVerifier.create(connectable)
                .expectSubscription() //expectNoEvent counts the subscription as an event
                .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(3))
                .then(connectable::connect)
                .expectNext("Test1", "Test2")
                .expectComplete()
                .verify();
}
```

Note the `expectSubscription` first. This avoid `expectNoEvent` from blowing up because it considers the act of subscribing as an event (and there is still a subscription to the `ConnectableFlux` itself - it just prevents subscription to its own upstream until you call `connect()`).